# customizing localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: objective-c, core-data, iphone

I am sorting and sectioning a tableview using the first letter of an array of strings, just like the Contacts app does. I'm using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController to drive the tableview. I use the first letter of the word, and if the letter isn't Only issue is, when I use a sort description with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:, it seems to generate the list of sections with: '#', 'A', 'B' ... 'Z'. I want the # to come at the end of the list, not the first (just like the Contacts app, again). Is there any creative way I could accomplish this?

Here's how I'm creating the NSFetchedResultsController:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:100];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorLetter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionLetter" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorLetter, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionLetter" cacheName: nil]; // NOTE: set the cache name to nil for testing ...

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't customize sort descriptors when using the NSFetchedResultsController. You have to go with the standard sorting selectors, like "localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare".

The way I ended up doing this is to take the NSFetchedResultsController results and tweaking the boilerplate code for setting up the tableView with my own mapping of indexPaths, where I off-set the 0th section to the last section of the table. It's a bit of work, and it might just be better to forget using NSFetchedResultsController and load all the objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `‑localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` selector to compare the objects, you should instead initialise your `NSSortDescriptor` using the `+sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` class method.

This method allows you to pass in an `NSComparator` which is a block that contains code to compare two objects and sort them. You can compare them any way you like.

If you've never used blocks before, [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) will be helpful.